# Samba & AutoFS Hide shares

Tags: samba4

just want to ask if it possible to hide Samba-shares (through AutoFS) that users don't have access to ?
I have 5 shares for 5 different groups of users (ex: group1...4 and Public).  When member of group1 logins into client PC - he must see only Group1 & Public Samba share, and same for other groups.

Have tried to add next in smb.conf file:
"hide unreadable = yes" - in every share and/or 
"access based share enum=yes" - in Global section -> Works perfect as i need, but only through command in terminal : smbclient -L "IP-Server" -U "username".

When i use Samba-share through AutoFS, after user login - user see All shares, but i need to hide shares that users don't have access to.

Thanks

My configs:

auto.master

`/home  auto.home --timeout=60 --ghost
/samba  auto.samba --timeout=60 --ghost`

auto.home

```
* -rw,sync,rsize=16384,wsize=16384,hard,intr,file_mode=0600,dir_mode=0700 "ServerIP":/Share/private/&
```

auto.samba

```
Public -fstype=cifs,rw,credentials=/root/.smb/.${USER},uid=${USER},gid=grppublic,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770 ://"ServerIP"/Share/public
Group1 -fstype=cifs,rw,credentials=/root/.smb/.${USER},uid=${USER},gid=grpgroup1,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770 ://"ServerIP"/Share/Group1
Group2 -fstype=cifs,rw,credentials=/root/.smb/.${USER},uid=${USER},gid=grpgroup2,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770 ://"ServerIP"/Share/Group2
Group3 -fstype=cifs,rw,credentials=/root/.smb/.${USER},uid=${USER},gid=grpgroup3,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770 ://"ServerIP"/Share/Group3
Group4 -fstype=cifs,rw,credentials=/root/.smb/.${USER},uid=${USER},gid=grpgroup4,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770 ://"ServerIP"/Share/Group4
```

smb.conf

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
security = user
netbios name = project
passdb backend = tdbsam
printing = cups
printcap name = cups
load printers = yes
cups options = raw
passwd program = /bin/yppasswd %u
domain logons = no
hosts allow = 192.168.1.
access based share enum = yes

[public]
path = /Share/public
valid users = @grpall
write list = @grpall
force group = grpall
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = no
create mask = 0660
directory mask = 0770
hide unreadable = no

[group1]
path = /Share/Group1
valid users = @grpgroup1
force group = grpgroup1
browseable = no
writeable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = no
create mask = 0660
directory mask = 0770
hide unreadable = yes

[group2]
path = /Share/Group2
valid users = @grpgroup2
force group = grpgroup2
browseable = no
writeable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = no
create mask = 0660
directory mask = 0770
hide unreadable = yes
...and so on for all groups with their paths and permissions
```